# Interpreting "Only Bill did any of the homework."

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does *any of* within:

> "Only Bill did **any of** the homework."

mean *some of* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking yes, *any of* leaves room for some of it not to be done. Otherwise, the statement would (should) be

> Only Bill did the homework"

Depending on the context, however, it may refer to the rest of the students doing literally none of it, while Bill did the assignment as expected. The speaker may be using *any of* to put emphasis on the lack of work done by the rest of the class